# How can i set the same sorting of one array to another?

Tags: java, arraylist

for example:

```
arrayList1 [3, 2, 4, 1]
arrayList2 [me, you, myself, i]
```

and the output will be:

```
arrayList1 [1, 2, 3, 4]
arrayList2 [i, you, me, myself]
```

Comment: Implement any sorting algorithm you like and swap both the arrays together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do by creating a new `List` and simply replacing the words using the num List as the new `indices`.  Then sort the nums.

```
        List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(3,2,4,1);
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("me","you","myself", "i");
        List<String> sortedWords = new ArrayList<>(words);

        // first copy the words to their future location.
        for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            int idx = nums.get(i)-1;
            sortedWords.set(idx,words.get(i));
        }

        // sort the nums
        Collections.sort(nums);

        // print the lists
        System.out.println(nums);
        System.out.println(sortedWords);
```

And of course, you can just implement a simple sorting algorithm.

```
        List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(3, 2, 4, 1);
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("me", "you",
                "myself", "i");

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 1; i++) {
            int n = nums.get(i);
            int savek = i;
            for (int k = i + 1; k < nums.size(); k++) {
                if (n > nums.get(k)) {
                    savek = k; // save index for max value
                }
            }
            // swap if necessary   
            if (savek != i) {
                swap(nums, i, savek);
                swap(words, i, savek);
            }
        }

        // print the lists
        System.out.println(nums);
        System.out.println(words);
```

Helper swap method

```
    public static <T> void swap(List<T> list, int i,
            int j) {
        T t = list.get(i);
        list.set(i, list.get(j));
        list.set(j, t);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add all elements to a TreeMap, which will sort your entries by their key.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < arrayList1.size(); i++) {
    map.put(arrayList1.get(i), arrayList2.get(i));
}

arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use any sorting method for the int array, and then swap the elements from both the int and String array together.

```
        int a[] = {3, 2, 4, 1};
        String b[]= {"me", "you", "myself", "i"};
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) 
            {
                if (a[i] > a[j]) 
                {
                   int temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                    String tmp=b[i];
                    b[i]=b[j];
                    b[j]=tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println(a[a.length - 1]);

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(b[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.print(b[b.length - 1]);
```